# Prob. that half of 20K coins are heads

Tags: probability

X unbiased coins. What is the probability that half of them exactly are heads. Please answer question where X= 20, 30, and 20000.

Comment: [probability of getting 50 heads from tossing a coin 100 times](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/12348/probability-of-getting-50-heads-from-tossing-a-coin-100-times)

Comment: [What is the probability that exactly $i$ heads will result from $n$ coin tosses?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1752/what-is-the-probability-that-exactly-i-heads-will-result-from-n-coin-tosses)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there's "half" of them for $X = 3$. For the $X = 2$ case, we just find the probability of $HT$ and $TH$, making it $\frac{1}{2}$. For 20,000, though, it's ${N \choose N/2}2^{-N}$, where $N$ is 20,000.